# nivo slider & lightbox video challenge

Tags: jquery, video, triggers, click, nivo-slider

I am using to different plug-ins: **Nivo slider** & a **Lightbox.**

I want to be able to click an image in the slider to trigger (only jQuery) an action to show my video in a lightbox.

My current solution is to link to another page that has:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#videoanchor').trigger('click');
}); </script>
```

Which works fine but takes them away from the original page and every time they visit the video page (which is where the link takes them) this video pops up.
I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#sliderimg').click(function(){
$('#videoanchor').trigger('click');
});</script>
```

Didn't work.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

if it is youtube video and address contains /v/etc.... change v into "watch"